# What is needed to use kubernetes port forwarding through a proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, kubernetes, socat, helm

I have a kubernetes cluster that I can reach through an nginx proxy.

I can do `kubectl get deployments -n kube-system` without issue.

However, I'm trying to use helm. Helm is throwing an error:

`Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: unable to upgrade connection: query parameter "port" is required`

From researching this, it looks like an error with port forwarding with kubernetes. In order for helm to work, kubernetes port forwarding must work first, ie:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864580/error-forwarding-ports-upgrade-request-required-error-in-helm-of-a-kubernete

Indeed, trying:

`kubectl -n kube-system port-forward <tiller-deploy-Pod> <some_port>:44134`

Does not work through the proxy.

So...what exactly is needed to get kubernetes port forwarding working through a proxy?

Do I need to set up a tcp proxy such as socat on the proxy server for port 44134? If so, do I just proxy traffic to 44134 on the kubernetes master?

Comment: to use helm you only need a kubectl point to your cluster and able to connect and helm init

Comment: This is not the case. "kubectl port-forward" must work. Try running "kubectl port-forward" through an nginx proxy and you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @catpants what does it say when you do `kubectl -n kube-system port-forward <tiller-deploy-Pod> <some_port>:44134` ?

Comment: @catpants Hello, have you've managed to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do not go through NGINX for that. Try talking to one of your nodes directly.
Even if the service you try to talk to is on (let's say) node No3, Kubernetes internal Proxy service should forward the traffic on it's underlying private network (flanneld or which ever network stack you use) to the correct node without you noticing it.